# Understanding pointer casting on struct type in C

Tags: c, json, parsing

I'm trying to understanding the pointer casting in this case.

```
# https://github.com/udp/json-parser/blob/master/json.c#L408

#define json_char char
typedef struct _json_object_entry
{
   json_char * name;
   unsigned int name_length;

   struct _json_value * value;

} json_object_entry;
typedef struct _json_value
{
struct
  {
     unsigned int length;

     json_object_entry * values;

     #if defined(__cplusplus) && __cplusplus >= 201103L
     decltype(values) begin () const
     {  return values;
     }
     decltype(values) end () const
     {  return values + length;
     }
     #endif

  } object;
}
(*(json_char **) &top->u.object.values) += string_length + 1;
```

Due to what I see `top->u.object.values` has the address of the first element of values ( type : json_object_entry ), and then we get the address of values, casting it to char, .. And from here I'm lost. I don't really understand the purpose of this.

// Notes : This is two pass parser for those who wonders what is this.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps its using the cast to constrain the updating of the value to a single byte (char) as opposed to whatever the value type may be declared as, which might be (int)...

Comment: The casting is to `char**` so that dereferencing it (note the first `*` after the superfluous outer bracket) yields a pointer again, albeit one pointing to char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author here (guilty as charged...)

In the first pass, `values` hasn't yet been allocated, so the parser cheats by using the same field to store the amount of memory (length) that's going to be required when it's actually allocated in the second pass.

```
if (state.first_pass)
    (*(json_char **) &top->u.object.values) += string_length + 1;
```

The cast to `json_char` is so that we add multiples of `char` to the length, rather than multiples of `json_object_entry`.

It is a bit (...OK, more than a bit...) of a dirty hack re-using the field like that, but it was to save adding another field to `json_value` or using a union (C89 unions can't be anonymous, so it would have made the structure of `json_value` a bit weird).

There's no UB here, because we're not actually using `values` as an array of structs at this point, just subverting the type system and using it as an integer.

Comment: Thanks James for answer :)

Answer (score 2):

`_json_value::values` is a pointer to the beginning of (or into) an array of `json_object_entry`s. The code adjusts its value by a few bytes, e.g in order to skip a header or such before the actual data. Because the pointer is typed one can without casting only change its value in quants of `sizeof(_json_object_entry)`, but apparently the offset can have any value, depending on some `string_length`. So the address of the pointer is taken, cast to the address of a char pointer (a char pointer can be changed in 1 increments), dereferenced so the result is a pointer to char residing at the same place as the real `u.object.values`, and then assigned to.

One should add that such code may break at run time if the architecture demands a minimal alignment for structures (possibly depending on their first element, here a pointer) and the string length can have a value which is not a multiple of that alignment. That would make the code UB. I'm not exactly sure whether the code is nominally UB if the alignment is preserved.

Comment: That's a great answer!

Comment: really nice answer. It's predicted from an experienced engineer. But I have another question rises, why would someone do such hidden data store like that ?

Comment: I think the code is from here: https://github.com/udp/json-parser/blob/master/json.h. It's fairly complex; I have read it a couple times and am still not sure whether I get it right. It tries to handle different data types uniformly and store them in a union. I assume that sometimes the data can contain strings (the parsing code tests for a double quote and adjusts `values` accordingly when it finds the closing one, I think). I suppose that the data can contain data of various types, and a (leading?) string is one of them.

Comment: I would prefer a clearer separation between tokenizing and interpreting the data, but I have also seen that a good text book architecture can become a lot of code while mixing tokenizing (e.g. identifying string boundaries in a text) with data building can be very efficient. Since the author tries to build a "Very low footprint JSON parser" (https://github.com/udp/json-parser) I assume efficiency was the driving design principle here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    json_object_entry * values;
...
}

(*(json_char **) &top->u.object.values) += string_length + 1;
```

forgetting type correctness, you can collapse the & and *:

```
((json_char **) top->u.object.values) += string_length + 1;
```

top->u.object.values is indeed the pointer to first element of values array. It is typecasted to a pointer to a pointer to json_char, and then advanced string_length + 1 characters. The net result is that top->u.object.values now points (string_length + 1) json_chars ahead of what it used to.